# Handling Swipe Guesture in Windows 8 Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to implement a custom control which consists of a grid with some canvas elements as children , When a swipe action is made on the grid , I am intended to preform some operation with the canvas elements .
I am unable to handle the swipe for the grid , i have posted the same in the 
[msdn - win8 Dev forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/6bf14cda-9bbf-47a3-b4d8-acbf742bbf1b/#6bf14cda-9bbf-47a3-b4d8-acbf742bbf1b)

Comment: I tried to handle the pointer moved , enter delegates to mimic the swipe , But I am unable to differentiate the Right->Left and Left->Right gesture.

I am not aware to set the GestureRecoginizer object for a grid.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was in the same boat as you guys, since there was no samples out there on how this was done, but after perusing and scrutinizing the MSDN documentation on how a swipe gesture is implemented on a Windows 8 Store app using C#, this is what i came up with (and it works for my app which requires swiping up / down / left / right):

First of all, instead of the GestureRecognizer, the Manipulation events need to be used, so on the grid that you want to handle the swiping (lets' say you make it so that it takes the whole screen so it interprets the gestures) do the following:

I called my grid **swipingSurface** and i'm handling manipulation modes for both the Y-axis and X-axis:

```
swipingSurface.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
```

Then wire up the manipulation events that you want to be notified, in my case i just want to know then the manipulation started and when it ended:

```
swipingSurface.ManipulationStarted += OnManipulationStarted;
swipingSurface.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;
```

Do whatever you want on your manipulation started, such as getting the initial point if you want. But the actual trick is on the ManipulationCompleted event, in which you need to get the Velocities resulting from your gesture, as follows:

```
public void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e) {
    var velocities = e.Velocities;      
}
```

The ManipulationCompletedEventArgs **Velocities** property will bring back a struct of type **ManipulationVelocities**, which contains other properties inside:

-*Angular*: The rotational velocity in degrees per millisecond.

-*Expansion*: The expansion, or scaling, velocity in DIPs per millisecond.

-*Linear*: The straight line velocity in DIPs per millisecond.

I'm actually looking at the **Linear** velocity, which is a **Point** that contains X and Y values indicating the direction in which the gesture was performed; for example, if the swipe was upward, you will notice that the Y value is positive, and if its down the Y value is negative; the same goes for the X value, if the swipe is left, the X values are negative and if the swipe is right, the X values are positive, so you can play around with those values and check your swiping direction, final points, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, the swipe part is solved thanks to you. But now I need to solve an issue (dunno if you also solved it). The swipe doesn't work in a blank space (imagine that you have a grid, with empty cells... you can't swipe on those cells even if you catch those events in the Grid or in the parent)

Comment: @Tiago Almeida are you receiving all the events when the grid is empty ?

Comment: @RajmohanKathiresan Eventually I have solved it. It turns out that you need to have a background so you can receive events. Even if that background is set to Transparent.

Comment: Newb question; is there a way to do this without code-behind?

Comment: this works fine while using mouse pointer in windows laptop but doesn't work for touch in windows tablet/stimulator. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting ManipulationMode on your swipe-able control and handling the Manipulation~ events. Note that some controls might stop bubbling of UI events, so if you say put your control inside of a Button or a ScrollViewer - the events might not work.

Comment: Thank You , I will try with that , can u please guide me to assign a gesture for a grid .

 `geustureRecorgizer = new GestureRecognizer();
            geustureRecorgizer.CrossSlideHorizontally = true;
            geustureRecorgizer.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.CrossSlide;
            geustureRecorgizer.CrossSliding += new TypedEventHandler<GestureRecognizer, CrossSlidingEventArgs>(Guesture_Sliding);`


How to assign this gesture to the grid

Comment: Sorry, I have not used GestureRecognizer yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out `SwipeHintThemeAnimation` that uses `GestureRecognizer` to hook up to a Rectangle control or modify it to use your Grid control, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.swipehintthemeanimation.aspx).