# Swipe gestures in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

In my app i want to be able to recognise certain gestures that occur on an ui element.

So far i have got this: (where main grid is the element)

```
mainGrid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
mainGrid.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;

public void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var velocities = e.Velocities;
}
```

but i get certain weird errors

> Error 1   No overload for 'OnManipulationCompleted' matches delegate
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventHandler' C:\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\Swell\Swell\MainPage.xaml.cs

reference : [Handling Swipe Guesture in Windows 8 Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798347/handling-swipe-guesture-in-windows-8-grid)

Answer (score 0):

OnManipulationCompleted is probably a method provided by your base class its signature does not match.

I suspect that you need to change the name to avoid a conflict such as:

```
mainGrid.ManipulationCompleted += MainGridManipulationCompleted;

public void MainGridManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var velocities = e.Velocities;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunatly it didnt work

Comment: We may need to see more code then since we don't have the context of surrounding code.  ex. what class is your ...Completed event a member of?

Answer (score 0):

So i think i fixed it guys

had to change 'ManipulationCompletedEventArgs' to 'ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgse'

```
mainGrid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
mainGrid.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;

public void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgse)
{
    var velocities = e.Velocities;
}
```

EDIT: didnt fully fix it,app crashes when getting velocities